# Sencha Ext JS Calendar - It is not possible to go to next day/week after clicking right arrow button

Tags: extjs, calendar, extjs7

Sencha ext JS framework version - 7.6.0
Sencha ext JS framework calendar component version - 7.6.0

Sometimes I am not able to go next day/week when right arrow button is clicked. After the clicking, same day/week remains.

Temporary workaround - If I click left arrow button, and then right arrow button again I am able to go to next day/week again.

What could be the reason of this? How can it be solved?

Expected result: After clicking right arrow button day/week will be changed to next day/week.

[Sencha Ext JS Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkceC.png)

Comment: I don't think this is a bug! The default behaviour of clicking next button is to set the next view based on current view(day/week/month).If the current view is "day" and After clicking right arrow button it will change to next day. check this, https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ksi it works fine!

Comment: This is the issue, I could replicate this in your provided link also. Here is the replication video: [Calendar-bug](https://www.loom.com/share/7a294484772645438583540aff813687?sid=6ba280e1-e909-44ab-81a1-9a08b4488761)

Comment: Did you see any error in console? Try removing the "eventStoreDefaults" in the fiddle  and check if the issue persists! So far i doubt that the issue might be related to prefetch of store events!